# How to get documents whose list contains all queried elements

Tags: mongodb, criteria, spring-data-mongodb

The problem I have is the following:
I have the structure

```
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private Set<String> ingredients;
```

and I am trying to create a criteria query to which I pass a list of strings and check whether the ingredients contains all of the elements of the query (preferably case insensitive).

What I have tried:

```
if (!recipeQuery.getIngredients().isEmpty()) {
            recipeQuery.getIngredients().stream()
                    .map(i -> Criteria.where("ingredients").regex(recipeQuery.getName(), "i"))
                    .forEach(query::addCriteria);
        }
```

Any attempts on searching for the case insensitive collection in another collection have been met with "Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'ingredients' criteria. Query already contains" at best

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to use `.all()` as in this example to make sure that all of the ingredients were in the queried list, but as it was mentioned in the comments, this does not solve the case insensitive issue:

```
if (!recipeQuery.getIngredients().isEmpty()) {
            Criteria categories = Criteria.where("ingredients").all(recipeQuery.getIngredients());
            query.addCriteria(categories);
        }
```

this solves the case issue as well

```
if (!recipeQuery.getIngredients().isEmpty()) {
            Criteria categories = new Criteria();
            categories.andOperator(recipeQuery.getIngredients().stream()
                    .map(i -> Criteria.where("ingredients").regex(".*" + i + ".*", "i"))
                    .toArray(Criteria[]::new));
            query.addCriteria(categories);
        }
```

Comment: What about case insensitivity?

Comment: still working on that one. if you have any suggestions, i'm listening

Comment: I had a similar requirement, and I ended up doing an `or` query with regex on each value. Not optimal I think, but I was working with only few values so it wasn't too bad.